# How to disable a <g:submitToRemote/> button

Tags: jquery, grails

I have an ajax form with a g:submitToRemote button on it. I would like to enable the button when a checkbox is checked on the form. I am using jQuery and YUI javascript libraries in my project and tried with both and still no solution. Upon viewing the source, I could see that the "id" attribute is discarded for g:submitToRemote. Is there a way that the g:submitToRemote button can be enabled/disabled upon any other event or is there any workaround to this?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: what html does g:submitToRemote generate ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the name attribute.  Grails will use that as the HTML id attribute as well.  Then you can disable/enable using the $('#foo') method.  Or you could do some sort of selector like $("input[name='foo']").

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- Whatever you have before your g:submitToRemote button-->
    <g:checkBox name="myCheckBox" />
    <g:submitToRemote name="myButton" />
    <!-- Whatever you have after your g:submitToRemote button-->

    <!-- Some jQuery to disable the button at the end of your document-->
    <g:javascript>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myCheckBox").change(function{
                // myButton is disabled if myCheckBox is checked
                if($("#myCheckBox").prop("checked")){
                    $("#myButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                else{
                    $("#myButton").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    </g:javascript>
</body>
</html>
```